# Sum all cells to the right of a column in each row using Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, row

So I've seen many pages on the generalized version of this issue but here specifically I would like to sum all values in a row after a specific column.

Let's say we have this df:

```
id    city      identity   q1   q2   q3
0110  detroit   ella       2    4    3
0111  boston    fitz       0    0    0
0112  philly    gerald     3    1    0
0113  new_york  doowop     8    11   2
0114  ontario   wazaaa     NA   11   NA
```

Now the df's I work with aren't usually with 3 "q" variables, they vary. Hence, I would like to rowSum every row but only sum the rows that are after the column `identity`.

Rows with NA are to be ignored.

Eventually I would like to take the rows which sum to 0 to be removed and end with a df that looks like this:

```
id    city      identity   q1   q2   q3
0110  detroit   ella       2    4    3
0112  philly    gerald     3    1    0
0113  new_york  doowop     8    11   2
```

Doing this in dplyr is the preference but not required.

EDIT:

I have added below the data of which this solution is not working for, apologies for the confusion.

```
df <- structure(list(Program = c("3002", "111", "2455", "2929", "NA", 
"NA", NA), Project_ID = c("299", "11", "271", "780", "207", "222", 
NA), Advance_Identifier = c(14, 24, 12, 15, NA, 11, NA), Sequence = c(6, 
4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 79), Item = c("payment", "hero", "prepayment_2", 
"UPS", "period", "prepayment", "yeet"), q1 = c("500", "12", "-1", 
"0", NA, "0", "0"), q2 = c("500", "12", "-1", "0", NA, "0", "1"
), q3 = c("500", "12", "2", "0", NA, "0", "2"), q4 = c("500", 
"13", "0", "0", NA, "0", "3")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Convert your character numbers to numeric before doing anything else.

Comment: apologies, keep up the good work akrun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use

```
out <- df1 %>%
   mutate(new = rowSums(select(., ((match('identity', names(.)) + 
           1):ncol(.))), na.rm = TRUE))
out
#    id     city identity q1 q2 q3 new
#1 110  detroit     ella  2  4  3   9
#2 111   boston     fitz  0  0  0   0
#3 112   philly   gerald  3  1  0   4
#4 113 new_york   doowop  8 11  2  21
```

and then `filter` out the rows that have 0 in 'new'

```
out %>%
    filter(new >0)
```

---

In the OP's updated dataset, the `type` of columns are `character`.  We can automatically convert the `type`s to respective types with

```
df %>%
    #type.convert %>% # base R
    # or with `readr::type_convert
     type_convert %>%
    ...
```

---

NOTE: The OP mentioned in the title and in the description about a `tidyverse` option.  It is not a question about efficiency.

Also, `rowSums` is a `base R` option.  Here, we showed how to use that in `tidyverse` chain.  I could have written an answer in `base R` way too earlier with the same option.

If we remove the `select`, it becomes just a `base R` i.e

```
df1$new < rowSums(df1[(match('identity', names(df1)) + 1):ncol(df1)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

#### Benchmarks

```
df = data.frame(id=sample(100,100), city=sample(LETTERS,100,TRUE), 
      identity=sample(letters,100,TRUE), q1=runif(100), q2=runif(100),q3=runif(100))
akrun = function(df1){
 rowSums(df1[(match('identity', names(df1)) + 1):ncol(df1)], na.rm = TRUE)
}



baz = function(df1){rowSums(
    df1[,(1+which(names(df1)=="identity")):ncol(df1),drop=FALSE]
    )}

microbenchmark({df$new=NULL;df2 = akrun(df)},{df$new=NULL;df$new=baz(df)})
#Unit: microseconds
#                                       expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
#  {     df$new = NULL     df2 = akrun(df) } 69.926 73.244 112.2078 75.4335 78.7625 3539.921   100
# {     df$new = NULL     df$new = baz(df) } 73.670 77.945 118.3875 80.5045 83.5100 3767.812   100
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 110:113, city = c("detroit", "boston", "philly", 
"new_york"), identity = c("ella", "fitz", "gerald", "doowop"), 
    q1 = c(2L, 0L, 3L, 8L), q2 = c(4L, 0L, 1L, 11L), q3 = c(3L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Comment: Error in x:y : NA/NaN argument ; my original df has NA's

Comment: Error in rowSums(select(., ((match("Item", names(.)) + 1):ncol(.))), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: @JohnnyThomas. Iss this error based on your original data or the data I showed here

Comment: just tried yours and it worked fine, added a snip of my code in the OP

Comment: @JohnnyThomas. The `q1` to `q4` are `character` class.  It hsould be converted to `numeric` first

Comment: @JohnnyThomas. You can add `df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('q')), as.numeric) %>%`

Comment: I see, is there a way to similarly change all columns right of "Item" (identity in the OP) from character to numeric?

Comment: that wouldn't work necessarily, there can be variety on what the column begins with depending on who's working on it

Comment: @JohnnyThomas. Try `df %>% type_convert %>%` (should automatically change the type based on the values)

Comment: You should try to have all scenarios/conditions right when you post and avoid adding them on the go..

Answer (score 9):

Base R version with zero extra dependencies:

[Edit: I always forget `rowSums` exists]

```
> df1$new = rowSums(
    df1[,(1+which(names(df1)=="identity")):ncol(df1),drop=FALSE]
    )


> df1
   id     city identity q1 q2 q3 new
1 110  detroit     ella  2  4  3   9
2 111   boston     fitz  0  0  0   0
3 112   philly   gerald  3  1  0   4
4 113 new_york   doowop  8 11  2  21
```

If you need to convert chars to numbers, use `apply` with `as.numeric`:

```
df$new = apply(df[,(1+which(names(df)=="Item")):ncol(df),drop=FALSE], 1, function(col){sum(as.numeric(col))})
```

BUT look out if they are really *factors* because this will fail, which is why converting things that look like numbers to numbers before you do anything else is a Good Thing.

## Benchmark

In case you are worried about speed here's a benchmark test of my function against the currently accepted solution:

```
akrun = function(df1){df1 %>%
   mutate(new = rowSums(select(., ((match('identity', names(.)) + 
           1):ncol(.))), na.rm = TRUE))}

baz = function(df1){rowSums(
    df1[,(1+which(names(df1)=="identity")):ncol(df1),drop=FALSE]
    )}
```

sample data

```
df = data.frame(id=sample(100,100), city=sample(LETTERS,100,TRUE), identity=sample(letters,100,TRUE), q1=runif(100), q2=runif(100),q3=runif(100))
```

Test - note I remove the `new` column from the source data frame each time otherwise the code keeps adding one of those into it (although `akrun` doesn't modify `df` in place it can get run after `baz` has modified it by assigning it the new column in the benchmark code).

```
> microbenchmark({df$new=NULL;df2 = akrun(df)},{df$new=NULL;df$new=baz(df)})
Unit: microseconds
                                       expr      min       lq       mean
  {     df$new = NULL     df2 = akrun(df) } 1300.682 1328.941 1396.63477
 {     df$new = NULL     df$new = baz(df) }   63.102   72.721   87.78668
    median        uq      max neval
 1376.9425 1398.5880 2075.894   100
   84.3655   86.7005  685.594   100
```

The tidyverse version takes 16 times as long as the base R version.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to akrun you can try

```r
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("q")),funs(as.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate(sum_new = rowSums(select(., starts_with("q")), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(sum_new>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i use `reduce` in  `purrr` to sum rows, it's the fastest way.

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with('q')),~!is.na(.)) %>% 
        mutate( Sum = reduce(select(., starts_with("q")), `+`)) %>% 
        filter(Sum > 0)
```